# Flicker slideshow on d6

Tags: 6, javascript

How do I add flicker photo album on D6 via "insert/ embedded Media" button?
I don't know which links to copy on the fields:
(general + advanced)

[image]

Comment: [Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol) I hope you're in the process of upgrading to 7 or 8.

Comment: I do ... But NOW I'm stuck. Any practical info?